# In Power BI, how can I calculte with is the next value based on the timestamp, date, and user?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to build a table that shows me a PAGE_TITLE and the next PAGE_TITLE that the users normally go to in a session - like a user journey thing.

I have the following tables:

- `VW_DIM_PAGE` with the field `PAGE_TITLE`
- `VW_FCT_EVENT` with the fields `event_date` and `event_timestamp` to identify both time and `user_pseudo_id`, `session_id` to identify the user and his sessions and the metric `TOTAL_USERS`

These two tables have relationships through a key.
I want to build a measure named Next page_title that gives me the next page title for that user in that session

E.g

I want to know how many users do this journey:

| page_title | Next page_title | Total Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| homepage | about us | 100 |

I'd even want a third next page_title in the table if possible.

I have been trying different DAX I've seen in Google search, but nothing that I managed to work and since I am new to Power BI, I can't find a way by myself

Comment: Show your sample data from both tables.